# URL parsing difference: Node.js vs. Python

Tags: python, node.js, uri

I'm trying to convert the following url to a valid nodejs URL object: `https://4www.xn--www-y8c4rla.a-k-d.ru`. In this case I expect it to fail.

Due to reasons I need to detect this domain being invalid in different scripts - one in Node.js *and* one in Python. Both, should lead to the same result.
However, this is not the case as the results differ.

I try to parse it in `node.js` using the URLs class constructor:

```
let domain = "https://4www.xn--www-y8c4rla.a-k-d.ru"
let domain_obj = new URL(domain);
```

I get a `TypeError: Invalid URL`, which make sense to me given the weirdness of the URL.

When trying the parsing with `Python` usign the [validators](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) class:

```
domain = "https://4www.xn--www-y8c4rla.a-k-d.ru"
validation = validators.domain(domain)
```

.. the value vor `validation` results in `True`.
It seems this method only uses some kind of regex for conversion, which seems not to be sufficient for this example Url.

Further: when I access the domain using Chromium, I am redirected to `a-k-d.ru`
When doing the same with Firefox, the domain is invalid. To me it seems Chrome performs some kind of auto-conversion of the URLs that I cannot trace.

Any idea which additions are considered in Node.js when converting URLs? So I can extend my python procedure accordingly in order the get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself:
as already suggested Python's validators only uses regex-based parsing.
However, Node.JS' URL constructor seems in addition also to check the domain for valid [IDNA/Punycode](https://nodejs.org/api/punycode.html) de/encoding.

So, I extended my Python procedure with the following pre-check:

```
import idna

# omit protocol preamble!
punycode_domain = "xn--www-y8c4rla.a-k-d.ru" 

try:
    unicode_domain = idna.decode(punycode_domain)
    print(f"Unicode domain: {unicode_domain}")
except idna.IDNAError as e:
    print(f"Error decoding Punycode domain: {e}")
```

Now, at least for my case the URL validation from my Node.js procedure equals my Python procedure (that further uses `urlparse`from  `urllib.parse`).